# NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.wstx.handler.WSATGenerator

Tags: web-services, websphere, apache-axis, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using the web client for **web service**. Client stub is generated with **Axis 2**. Everything is deployed on **WebSphere 7.0**.

When deployed on my developer machine (websphere instance run inside **IBM RAD Eclipse**) I'm connected with remote web service. However, on test machine, the error is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.wstx.handler.WSATGenerator (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ws.wstx.WSTXClientTCMImpl.handleInbound(WSTXClientTCMImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.wstx.WSTXClientTCMImpl.cleanupContext(WSTXClientTCMImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.ThreadContextMigratorUtil.performContextCleanup(ThreadContextMigratorUtil.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.postExecute(AxisInvocationController.java:657)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:589)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:130)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)
    at $Proxy94.getList(Unknown Source)
```

The **ear** that is deployed there is made by me on my development machine, so it's exactly the same code. So I suppose that it's some configuration issue. However, I have no idea, what part of configuration can be responsible for that.

So, I have the question, what is this `WSATGenerator`, and in which **jar** it should be available? Is it a standard library on WebSphere, or must it be manually configured? What configuration differences could cause that error thrown on test server and no by me?

I'm running Windows 7, the test machine is on Unix. Both machines are 64bit.

**--edit--**

Before `NoClassDefFoundError`, there is throws `ExceptionInInitializerError`:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
    at com.ibm.ws.wstx.handler.WSATGenerator.<clinit>(WSATGenerator.java:127)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.wstx.WSTXClientTCMImpl.migrateThreadToContext(WSTXClientTCMImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.ThreadContextMigratorUtil.performMigrationToContext(ThreadContextMigratorUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.preExecute(AxisInvocationController.java:608)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:570)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.systinet.jaxrpc.rpc.ServiceFactoryImpl incompatible with com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.rpc.ServiceFactory
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.wstx.WSATServices$1.run(WSATServices.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.wstx.WSATServices.<clinit>(WSATServices.java:74)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    ... 89 more
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same problem

Comment: @AlexCuervo not as far as I can remember. I'm generating client now only with maven pluggin, running on IBM JRE, so namely through IBM JAX-WS version.

Comment: might be solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028408/error-in-ws-client-noclassdeffounderror-com-ibm-ws-wstx-handler-wsatgenerator