# Error in WS client, NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.wstx.handler.WSATGenerator

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws, webservice-client

I'm using the web client generation tool of IBM RAD Eclipse for web service. In all generated classes I have the following comment at the beginning.

```
//
// Generated By:JAX-WS RI IBM 2.1.1 in JDK 6 (JAXB RI IBM JAXB 2.1.3 in JDK 1.6)
//
```

I export the generated project to a JAR file and then add it to my EAR. When I call to WebService with the Client stub from my web application I get the following exception:

```
[26/09/13 14:17:15:737 CEST] 0000001f servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Se ha creado una excepción no detectada en uno de los métodos de servicio del servlet action en la aplicación WATTEAR. Excepción creada: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.wstx.handler.WSATGenerator (initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
at com.ibm.ws.wstx.WSTXClientTCMImpl.handleInbound(WSTXClientTCMImpl.java:100)
at com.ibm.ws.wstx.WSTXClientTCMImpl.cleanupContext(WSTXClientTCMImpl.java:81)
at org.apache.axis2.util.ThreadContextMigratorUtil.performContextCleanup(ThreadContextMigratorUtil.java:192)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.postExecute(AxisInvocationController.java:630)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:562)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:118)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:82)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:295)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:158)
at $Proxy37.getFlows(Unknown Source)
at es.isban.webservices.WSAbacus.getFlows(WSAbacus.java:114)
at com.bsch.watt.operaciones.util.AbacusConnector.obtenerFlujosPrestamo(AbacusConnector.java:186)
at com.bsch.watt.operaciones.services.PrestamosService.obtenerFlujosSinPrestamo(PrestamosService.java:553)
at com.bsch.watt.operaciones.AltaOperacionPrestamosCob.comprobarCampañaPrestamoCob(AltaOperacionPrestamosCob.java:1041)
at com.bsch.watt.operaciones.AltaOperacionAction.execute(AltaOperacionAction.java:154)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:225)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1176)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:427)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1449)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

What is this WSATGenerator, and in which jar it should be available? Is it a standard library on WebSphere, or must it be manually configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the IBM Websphere JAX-WS runtime in your client application. The class definition which fails to be found resides in the com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.0.0.jar.